# nodejs checking permissions for systemchannel before sending a message

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I am debugging a permisions check logic.  What I want to do is gracefully handle for cases where I do and don't have permission to do so.  Here's my code:

```
    console.log(`permissions for me: ${JSON.stringify(guild.systemChannel.permissionsFor(guild.me).has('SEND_MESSAGES'))}`)

    //joined a server
    try{
        //Check for system channel
        if ( undefined == guild.systemChannel) {
            console.error(`${error}: guild.systemChannel does not exist during guildCreate callback`)
        }
        else if( ( guild.systemChannel) && ( !guild.systemChannel.permissionsFor(guild.me).has('SEND_MESSAGES') ) ) {
            console.error(`${error}: guild.systemChannel permissions to write are not available, during guildCreate callback`)
        }
        else {
            //Sends message to system channel
            guild.systemChannel.send('Thank you for adding me to your server!')
...
```

The log message indicates "true" when I join a server.  It turns out this server has custom privilege overrides for the systemchannel, and doesn't allow @everyone send-messages permission.  However, the bot requested send-messages permissions as part of its role, and thus the console log message indicates true.

the `guild.systemChannel.send('Thank...)` message fails, with Discord throwing an error saying permissions failure:

```
/home/path/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:154
      throw new DiscordAPIError(request.path, data, request.method, res.status);
            ^

DiscordAPIError: Missing Access
    at RequestHandler.execute (/home/path/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:154:13)
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
...
```

So if I change the server permissions on the systemchannel and make it @everyone can send messages, the code works....it sends the welcome message.

so I have a problem with my error checking logic above it.  I think the roles vs. bot permissions are in conflict...how to check correctly?

Comment: Can’t you use a simple `channel.send(…).catch(err => {…})`?

Comment: @MrMythical, can you help me understand why the try/catch block around the section doesn't catch this, but I'd have to wrap one directly on that promise?

Comment: You must add `await` in front of it so that it waits for the resolve or reject. It’s much easier with `.catch` though

Comment: ok got it, that makes sense.  yes both worked.  If you want to submit as an answer, I'll grade accordingly! @MrMythical thanks again!

Comment: I just posted the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You must `await` the promise in a try/catch block. Without doing that, the try/catch doesn’t detect it since it takes time to resolve. Adding `await` will force it to wait and will catch the error. A simple `.catch()` is much easier though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting the answer on behalf of @MrMythical 's comments...the await or the .catch was fine.  Although I think it is because of my C-based background that the concept of a contained try-catch block not catching things bugs me.  I think this is because the sync/async nature of this code flow, the execution can exit the block before the exception is caught.